# How can I simulate a click event on a Google Chart?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

E.g. using `jQuery` I do

```
$svg.find('g:nth-of-type(1) text').click()
```

but nothing happens, i.e. no `select` event is triggered.

The target element above is correct, it exists and it's in the middle of a pie chart section, which when manually clicked sends a `select` event.

This is for the [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart) library.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish, do you simply want the pie slice to be selected?

Comment: @WhiteHat I want to simulate a user clicking on a pie slice inside a Cypress E2E test. With real interaction, this triggers the goggle chart event `select`.

Answer (score 1):

to trigger an event in google charts, you can use the [trigger](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=en#trigger) method...

```
google.visualization.events.trigger(source_visualization, event_name, event_args);
```

the select event does not normally receive any arguments,
to determine which row / pie slice was selected / unselected,
you have to call method `getSelection` on the chart.

`getSelection` will return an array with an object for each row that was selected
it will return an empty array if a row was unselected

when we trigger the select event, if you want the chart to visually show something was selected,
you will need to pass arguments to the select event to indicate what should be selected,
then use chart method `setSelection` to visually show something was selected.

if no arguments are received by the select method,
then you know it was called by user interaction, and not a manual trigger.

see following example...
the select event is triggered manually, when the chart's ready event is fired.

we pass arguments to the select event, to let it know which row should be selected.
then use `setSelection` to visually indicate

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work', 11],
    ['Eat', 2],
    ['Commute', 2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep', 7]
  ]);
  var options = {
    title: 'My Daily Activities'
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    // trigger select event
    google.visualization.events.trigger(chart, 'select', [{row: 0}]);
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function (args) {
    // determine if arguments were received
    if (args) {
      // set chart selection using arguments received from trigger
      chart.setSelection(args);
    }
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @WhiteHat, but as stated in the method docs "Called by visualization implementers." I am not an implementer, but a tester and the source visualization instance (even the library itself) is not available to me in the testing environment. Am I missing something?

Comment: understood, in the code you posted, try using one of the `<path>` elements, rather than `<g>`

Comment: I was not selecting a `<g>` element, but a `<text>` element. Using `<path>` also does not work.